# How to fix the 'Keyword not supported: port' error when creating a database with EF Core and SQL Server Express?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I get this error when I try to create my database using migrations. I am using SQL Server Express with Windows authentication.

> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'port'.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
> at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms)     at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.CreateDbConnection() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.get_DbConnection() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<Exists>b__0(DateTime giveUp) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.b__0(DbContext c, TState s)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
>
> Keyword not supported: 'port'.

This is my connection string:

```
Server=WILMAN\\SQLEXPRESS,5000;Database=UCABPagaloTodo;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustedServerCertificate=True"
```

Help please - I am stuck at this error

Comment: don't think you're supposed to combine named instance with port, it's either or. Try WILMAN,5000

Comment: Is TCP/IP enabled? https://www.papercut.com/help/manuals/ng-mf/common/ext-db-specific-ms-sql-express/

Answer (score 0):

verify your connection string. You are probably not connecting correctly.